# What is causing this Youtube embed to disappear in FF & Safari, but not Chrome and IE?

Tags: youtube

I'm experimenting with posting an embedded youtube video [on this page](http://www.hptpoker.com/indexbeta.php).

It completely disappears in the latest versions FF and Safari, and I'm completely stumped with what's causing it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you could try the proper iframe code as given by youtube

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KhUr_bvECr0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks the problem is in this file http://www.hptpoker.com/stylesheet.css line 257

```css
.youtubebackground {
        margin-left: 62px;
        height:275px;
        left:50%;
        position:absolute;
        top:126px;
        width:423px;
        z-index:7;
        background:url("youtubebackground.jpg") no-repeat center top transparent;
}
```

This fragment of code make a layer to hide flash.

There are few modes (wmode) to embed a plugin on a webpage. Some of them are quite broken and doesn't respect layering, it isn't possible to hide plugin content with a html element. It looks it was fixed in Firefox and Safari.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html